# Visual Studio 2015 typescript "public readonly name: type" marked as error

Tags: typescript, syntax, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, if i write a .ts file with:

```
class MyClass {
    public pageSize: number;
}
```

no errors are marked (underlined).
If i write instead

```
class MyClass1 {
    public readonly pageSize: number;
}
```

i get weird underlines, but the code compiles.
Any clue?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: Sorry i'm really new in typescript, i would to use 2.0, but i've not set it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readonly properties was only [introduced in typescript 2](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#read-only-properties-and-index-signatures), so if you want to use it then you have to compile using typescript 2.

Your code is compiled [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClass1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20pageSize%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D) without errors as it uses typescript 2.

[Here's how](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/) to use it with visual studio.